# what the numeric value mean in hyperledger fabric channel configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i'm studying the part of channel configuration so i see the config block of json format.
i don't know what the type means and what the numeric value of type mean.
Can anyone explain to me? Thank you

```
{
  "data": {
    "data": [
      {
        "payload": {
          "data": {
            "config": {
              "channel_group": {
                "groups": {
                  "Application": {
                    "groups": {
                      "Org1MSP": {
                        "groups": {},
                        "mod_policy": "Admins",
                        "policies": {
                          "Admins": {
                            "mod_policy": "Admins",
                            "policy": {
                              "type": 1,  **what's this?**
                              "value": {
                                "identities": [
                                  {
                                    "principal": {
                                      "msp_identifier": "Org1MSP",
                                      "role": "ADMIN"
                                    },
                                    "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                  }
                                ],
                                "rule": {
                                  "n_out_of": {
                                    "n": 1,
                                    "rules": [
                                      {
                                        "signed_by": 0
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                },
                                "version": 0
                              }
                            },
                            "version": "0"
                          },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a numeric refering to the PolicyType enumeration :

```
message Policy {
    enum PolicyType {
        UNKNOWN = 0; // Reserved to check for proper initialization
        SIGNATURE = 1;
        MSP = 2;
        IMPLICIT_META = 3;
    }
    int32 type = 1; // For outside implementors, consider the first 1000 types reserved, otherwise one of PolicyType
    bytes policy = 2;
}
```

On your example, at least one admin of Org1 has to sign a transaction updating the network configuration.

[Source of the policy documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/policies.html)

Hope I answered your question

Comment: Thank you so much. i understand your opinion. i think you're right. Have a nice day!

Comment: @PierreHenriDebris Do you happen to know what policy type 2 is, i.e. policy type MSP?